# How to display object variable in web page?

Tags: javascript, object

I try to display object variable tag in web page.`  i want to display foreach product in products, display link + image + title

```
products: {
  product1: {
    link: skirollerprodukt1/affiliateId
    image: https://skirollet/image.png
    title: XRS02
  },
  product2: {
    link: skirollerprodukt2/affiliateId
    image: https://skirollet/image2.png
    title: XRS06
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your object literal is one big syntax error, which is going to cause any code using it to fail.  You'll need to fix that before any code can work on it.  Aside from that, what have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Apart from what answers might suggest, I would recommend that if you want to use a variable as a basis for a loop, always consider making it as an array; `products: []` instead of iterating over the properties&mdash;that in turn yield objects.